# TypeError: AWS.PinpointSMSVoice is not a constructor

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I am using "aws-sdk": "^2.302.0" in my node api.
Please find my code below

```
var pinpointsmsvoice = new AWS.PinpointSMSVoice({apiVersion: '2018-09-05'});

var params = {
    Content: {
        SSMLMessage: {
            LanguageCode: "en-US",
            Text: <MY_Template>,
            VoiceId: "Matthew"
        }
    },
    DestinationPhoneNumber: <destinationNumber>,
    OriginationPhoneNumber: <OriginationPhoneNumber>
};

//Try to send the message.
pinpointsmsvoice.sendVoiceMessage(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        log.error(err);            
    } else {
        log.info("Voice Message is sent successfully");
    }
});
```

Earlier it was working now I am getting an error as `TypeError: AWS.PinpointSMSVoice is not a constructor`

Can some help me anything missed?

Answer (score -1):

It's working with the latest aws-sdk version.